# total sum on 6 html inputs doesn't compute total with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

```
<form id="calcz">
<input type="number" value="6000">
<input type="number" value="240">
<input type="number" value="1440">
<input type="number" value="245">
<input type="number" value="600"> 
<input type="number" value="1200">
<output id="result"></output></form>
```

I try to add the results together and the values just display in order.

output
0600024014402456001200. I want the total sum.

Have no idea where the zero gets generated from.

```
<script>
var lengthz = document.forms.calcz.length;
var totalz = 0;
for(var z = 0; z <= lengthz-1; z++)
{
totalz += document.forms.calcz[z].value;
}    
document.write(totalz);
</script>
```

Comment: It's being treated as a String so convert to int `parseInt(document.forms.calcz[z].value)`

Comment: That is so weird, I thought if you don't single quote numbers it automatically treats them as numbers. I am guessing because it came from an html input the values as you said are treated as strings.

Answer (score 0):

> It's being treated as a String so convert to int `parseInt(document.forms.calcz[z].value)`
>   
> – [Sam Littlefair](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20721979)

Putting that into your code gives us:

```
<script>
  var lengthz = document.forms.calcz.length;
  var totalz = 0;
  for(var z = 0; z <= lengthz-1; z++)
  {
    totalz += parseInt(document.forms.calcz[z].value);
  }    
  document.write(totalz);
</script>
```